# Can I set Texmaker to auto-expand sections when I use search?

Tags: texmaker

In Texmaker, I can collapse sections of the document to make it easier to navigate. However, when I search for a term, and it appears in one of these sections, the window does not jump to it and it remains hidden (because it is collapsed).

Is there a way to make Texmaker expand sections and jump to the location automatically?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a feature request for an editor.

Comment: Ancient question I know, but if Texmaker doesn't do this, or has no choice for it in the options, then the only real solution would be to contact the maintainer.